# Form Not Submitting after using slug in my model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, slug

I am working on a project, where I need to hide the primary key in the url so I implemented slug in all my models. But the model which is using the foreign key to another model does not seem to work properly. The form is taking values but is not getting submitted no matter what I do. I don't know what is wrong in my code.

views.py

```
  class CabinCreateView(CreateView):
    fields = '__all__'
    model = Cabin
    success_url = reverse_lazy("NewApp:logindex")


    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.cabin =  Cabin.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])[0]
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

models.py

```
class Centre(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length =250)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
                             message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 10 digits allowed.")
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=10, blank=True)  # validators should be a list
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Centre, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

   def __str__(self):
        return self.name

   def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("index")


 class Cabin(models.Model):
    random_string = str(random.randint(100000, 999999))
    centre_name = models.ForeignKey(Centre, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    code = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=False, unique=True, default=random_string)
    total_seats = models.IntegerField(blank='False')
    category=models.CharField(max_length=100, default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=False,default=None)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.category)
    super(Cabin, self).save(*args, **kwargs)



def __str__(self):
    return self.code

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("index")
```

template

```
 <form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
   <div class="form-group col col-md-3">
   <label>Centre Name</label>
   {{form.centre_name}}
   </div>
  <label for="{{form.code.id_for_label}" style="margin-left:200px;width:200%;white-space:nowrap;">Code</label>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Code" value="{{form.code.value}}" name="code" maxlength="6" id="id_code" style="width:500px; margin-left:200px;">


 <label for="{{form.total_seats.id_for_label}" style="margin-left:200px;width:200px;white-space:nowrap;">seats</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="seats" name="total_seats" id="id_total_seats" style="width:500px; margin-left:200px;">


  <label for="{{form.category.id_for_label}" style="margin-top:-40px">Category</label>
  <input type="text" name="category"  maxlength="100" id="id_category" placeholder="Category" style="width:500px";>



 <input type="submit"   value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" style=" height:30px;width:80px;padding-bottom:2em;"/>

  </form>
```

The centre form is working fine, but the cabin form does not submit after pressing submit. The page is getting reloaded that means the form not being valid. Also no errors come up at all.I have not posted {{form.errors}} with every fields because it was too much of code. I have applied it with all the fields.

Comment: You did not render the `{{ form.errors }}`?

Comment: See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages

Comment: I did not post the form.errors because it was getting too much of code. Also, comparedate is a js function. It is working fine.

Comment: @Srvastav4: but do you render the errors in the template? Including the errors *per field*?

Comment: Yes. I have included it in all the fields that require it.

Comment: You need to show your `Cabin` model.

Comment: I have posted it too.